# cURL: from ethical point of view, what the calls frequency is not harmful?

Tags: php, curl

**Question:**

Could anyone please let me know at what frequency calling someone's website via cURL is not considered harmful?

**Explanation:**

I am building a small web app, where I fetch wordpress posts and some of its information from a clients website.

(!) *Not as a web **scraper** , as they have to install mini-plugin that supplies only relevant information using my authkey.*

Because the amount of pages can vary from 10 to 1000+. I am not doing it in one call; So I have made a page with Ajax script that pulls max 50 pages per call. This Ajax url calls my fetch.php, verifies the url each time (including header) and then gets the information via cURL. Repeats until finished.

**Scenario:**

Let's imagine client website has 1000 pages. So I would need to make a call 20 times (without delays, it's likely to happen within 30s).

Also, might need to consider that because I have to verify Domain URL before each call, which also have cURL with get headers only(as faster alternative to get_headers()).

I believe it's effectively doubles the amount of calls to 40 times.

So, ethically do I need to make a delay? or such volume of calls is not considered harmful to the client's website?

Thank you

Comment: Can you perhaps make it configurable? Say, X calls simultaneously, with Y ms delay between calls. Then you can work together with the client to find out an optimal value which fetches fast enough yet doesn't generate too much load.

Comment: If you're downloading everything one by one, that's not harmful (technically), but if you're multithreading (sending all the request simultaneously) that may overload their system, even kill it

Comment: thank you for your comments, I do plan to sequence it for sure, no multithreading. wasn't sure if I also need to delay it if it higher than 20 calls for example.

Comment: _"I have to verify Domain URL before each call"_ - Isn't it better to do that call just once before you start fetching data? Surly you don't need to do that before every single call?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, I had a thoughts about that, and I believe I have to verify it each time, at least within my current script. While they can't directly edit domain url once they provided it and its written into DB and has reference id, by which ajax request takes it. Not verifying it each time, leaves the possibility that client will start doing first ajax, verify it, and then place a redirect on his domain to another domain(provided, they need to be quick), so I believe in need to verify it before each call. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not really following. Who is it that gives you the address? Is it the owner of the site you will make requests to? Also, how often does people just randomly set up redirects from their domains? How often are you going to make all these calls?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, site owner supplies the domain url. Which cannot be trusted blindly. Normal people wont do redirects, at least more often than its needed to, but I believe someone who has malicious intentions might do more than just forwarding their domain (after it was validated once) for your script to compromise it in some way.

Comment: But they need to do that just after you've verified it. Next time you're going to make other calls (or run this batch again), you will still do a validation before you start. Also, if they "have malicious intentions", why would they need to redirect the call at all? They could just let their current site give you a malicious  response. Then it won't matter if you verify the domain or not. I would rather put my efforts into verifying the data you get.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, yes, that's why _"I have to verify Domain URL before each call"_ :)

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, the whole point of making more than one call is because I don't want people left hanging for long and let them see something after fetching first batch is ready (i.e, batch of 50 pages instead of waiting for 1000 pages.) Re: They could just let their current site give you a malicious response. - true, my verifier takes care of a lot of that, maybe not all cases tho. (i.e. it wont allow calls to any *.php, *.jpeg, *.png urls) but if they would url_rewrite it that might be different story. Thank you for your discussion, realised that I need to add content-type check.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely to vary a lot, but as long as you make your calls sequentially one at a time I can't see that it could be harmful even for a small site. If you make them run at the same time it is another story.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I do plan to sequence them one after another.

My worry I guess, is that I try to avoid to look too fast to some systems as they can flag me as a bot, or issue an IP ban.

Comment: @MaximusLight - Some sites have request limits on how many calls you can make within a certain amount of time, but that will totally differ from site to site. There's no "one answer" for what frequency a site would detect you as a bot or not.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson thank you for your comment, will take a note of that. But is there perhaps any "rule of a thumb"?

Comment: @MaximusLight - Not more than what others have said: make the calls after one another and not at the same time. That might at least protect you from being labeled as a DDOS-attack.